# How to define friend function templates of a class template for the purpose of operator overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, operator-overloading, friend

I'm trying to get a friend function inside a templated class to compile, but the error message and warning I do not understand. I've made a demonstration of the issue. The error I'm getting is:

> prog.cpp:8:57: error: non-class, non-variable partial specialization C operator+(const B& lhs, const C& rhs);
>
> prog.cpp:15:59: warning: friend declaration 'C operator+(const B&, const C&)' declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
>     friend C operator+(const B& lhs, const C& rhs);
>
> prog.cpp:15:59: note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename A, typename B>
class C;

template<typename A, typename B>
C<A, B> operator+<A, B>(const B& lhs, const C<A, B>& rhs);

template<typename A, typename B>
struct C
{
    A val_;
    C operator+(const C& other) const;
    friend C<A, B> operator+(const B& lhs, const C<A, B>& rhs);
};

template<typename A, typename B>
C<A, B> C<A, B>::operator+(const C<A, B>& other) const
{
    C<A, B> c;
    c.val_ = this->val_ + other.val_;
    return c;
}

template<typename A, typename B>
 C<A, B> operator+(const B& lhs, const C<A, B>& rhs)
{
    C<A, B> c;
    c.val_ = lhs + rhs.val_;
    return c;
}

int main() 
{
    C<string, char> c0,c1;
    c0.val_ = " C0 ";
    c1.val_ = " C1 ";
    cout << "Stuct:" << (c0 + c1).val_ << '\n';
    cout << "Friend:" << ('~' + c1).val_ << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the first declaration of `operator+`, which is wrong.

Comment: This is an example of the problem. I need three forms in my actual code: C operator+(const C& other), C operator+(const B& other), and C operator(const B& lhs, const C& rhs). N.B. not actual compiling code, just the general forms of the need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This declaration:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
C<A, B> operator+<A, B>(const B& lhs, const C<A, B>& rhs);
```

...is wrong because of the `<A,B>` between `operator+` and `(`, I don't really know what you wanted to do here. You would use this form if you were to *specialize* a templated `operator+`, but you are not here, you are *overloading* one.

This declaration should be:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
C<A, B> operator+ (const B& lhs, const C<A, B>& rhs);
```

Then you should explicitely specify in your `friend` declaration that you want a specialized version by writting:

```
friend C<A,B> operator+<>(const B& lhs, const C<A,B>& rhs);
```

You need to put this before your `operator+`, otherwize the compiler will think this is a specialization of a non-templated function.

Anyway, if you have no real reason to put your code outside the `C` class, I would go @Jarod42 solution.

---

Your whole code should look like this:

```
// Declaration of struct C with delayed definition
template <typename A, typename B>
struct C;

// Initial declaration of templated operator+
template <typename A, typename B>
C<A, B> operator+ (const B&, const C<A, B>&);

// Definition of C
template <typename A, typename B>
struct C {

    friend C operator+<> (const B&, const C&);

    // This must be AFTER the templated operator+
    C operator+ (const C&) const;
};

template<typename A, typename B>
C<A, B> C<A, B>::operator+(const C<A, B>& other) const {

}

template<typename A, typename B>
C<A, B> operator+(const B& lhs, const C<A, B>& rhs) {

}
```

Comment: I do have such a reason. :) I've put in the suggested code changes in the example, but now I get the error: prog.cpp:19:24: error: declaration of 'operator+' as non-function
  friend C<A,B> operator+ <>(const B& lhs, const C<A,B>& rhs);
                        ^
prog.cpp:19:24: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
prog.cpp:19:26: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
  friend C<A,B> operator+ <>(const B& lhs, const C<A,B>& rhs)

Comment: @JadziaMD You need to put the ` C<A,B> operator+ <>(const B& lhs, const C<A,B>& rhs)` **before** any other non-templated `operator+` inside `C`. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest is to inline code inside the class:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct C
{
    A val_;
    C operator+(const C& other) const
    {
        C c;
        c.val_ = this->val_ + other.val_;
        return c;
    }

    friend C operator+ (const B& lhs, const C& rhs)
    {
        C c;
        c.val_ = lhs + rhs.val_;
        return c;
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f19c4ae7e0e53ea9)

The code not inlined in the class, which requires lot of attention as forward declaration order of declaration, *strange* syntax `<>`:

```
template <typename A, typename B> struct C;

template <typename A, typename B>
C<A, B> operator+ (const B& lhs, const C<A, B>& rhs);

template <typename A, typename B>
struct C
{
    A val_;

    friend C<A, B> operator+<> (const B& lhs, const C<A, B>& rhs);

    C operator+(const C& other) const;
};


template <typename A, typename B>
C<A, B> operator+ (const B& lhs, const C<A, B>& rhs)
{
    C<A, B> c;
    c.val_ = lhs + rhs.val_;
    return c;
}

template <typename A, typename B>
C<A, B> C::operator+(const C<A, B>& other) const
{
    C<A, B> c;
    c.val_ = this->val_ + other.val_;
    return c;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cd74624dfeed918)