# Error when defining friend operator== in a class within another template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a template class and another class within it. I must define operator== for that inner class but in a way that the definition and declration are separate. Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace myNamespace {
    template <typename T>
    class MyClass {
        public:
            class MyInnerClass {
                public:
                    MyInnerClass() : v{0} {};

                    // declaration
                    template <typename U>
                    friend bool operator==(const typename MyClass<U>::MyInnerClass& lhs, const typename MyClass<U>::MyInnerClass& rhs);

                private:
                    int v;
            };

        private:
            // ...
    };
}

namespace myNamespace {
    // definition
    template <typename U>
    bool operator==(const typename MyClass<U>::MyInnerClass& lhs, const typename MyClass<U>::MyInnerClass& rhs) {
        return lhs.v == rhs.v;
    }
}


int main() {
    using namespace myNamespace;

    MyClass<int>::MyInnerClass inner1;
    MyClass<int>::MyInnerClass inner2;
    
    // fails here
    std::cout << (inner1 == inner2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
tmp.cpp:39:26: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘myNamespace::MyClass<int>::MyInnerClass’ and ‘myNamespace::MyClass<int>::MyInnerClass’)
   39 |     std::cout << (inner1 == inner2) << std::endl;
      |                   ~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~
      |                   |         |
      |                   |         MyInnerClass<[...]>
      |                   MyInnerClass<[...]>
tmp.cpp:27:10: note: candidate: ‘template<class U> bool myNamespace::operator==(const typename myNamespace::MyClass<U>::MyInnerClass&, const typename myNamespace::MyClass<U>::MyInnerClass&)’
   27 |     bool operator==(const typename MyClass<U>::MyInnerClass& lhs, const typename MyClass<U>::MyInnerClass& rhs) {
      |          ^~~~~~~~
tmp.cpp:27:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
tmp.cpp:39:29: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘U’
   39 |     std::cout << (inner1 == inner2) << std::endl;
      |                             ^~~~~~
```

How do I specialize the template operator== such that this does not faile

Answer (score 1):

An operator overload of the form

```cpp
template <typename U>
bool operator==(const typename MyClass<U>::MyInnerClass& lhs,
                const typename MyClass<U>::MyInnerClass& rhs);
```

... is practically useless no matter where it's defined because `MyClass<U>::MyInnerClass` is a [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25245453/5740428). It is impossible to deduce `U` from such a function parameter, so the only way to call it would be through

```cpp
myNamespace::operator==<MyType>(a, b);
```

You can instead define the operator overload as a *hidden friend* where your `friend` declaration currently is:

```cpp
// note: MyClass<T>:: can be omitted here
friend bool operator==(const MyInnerClass& lhs, const MyInnerClass& rhs) {
    return lhs.v == rhs.v;
}
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ac748bnjr)*

This solution is preferable in general because it makes the operator overload a non-template.

*See similar question: [Templated Class Friend Operator Member Function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36988730/5740428)*

Answer (score 0):

Don't introduce a new template argument for the `friend` - use `T` (the outer class template argument). Also, you have to combine the definition with the declaration (because the `friend` declared this way is only visible through ADL):

```
#include <iostream>

namespace myNamespace {
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
   class MyInnerClass {
   public:
      MyInnerClass() : v{ 0 } {};

      friend bool operator==(const typename MyClass<T>::MyInnerClass& lhs, const typename MyClass<T>::MyInnerClass& rhs)
      {
         return lhs.v == rhs.v;
      }

   private:
      int v;
   };

private:
    // ...
};
}
```

Comment: I am confused here. Why can I not separate declaration and definition in this case, but I can do so in case where I do not have class within a class? Here is an example that compiles just fine: https://godbolt.org/z/8h77eGMY4